# Effective way to calculate different results of same op in a single run?

Tags: tensorflow

I am working on a probabilistic model of a NN which requires to draw random samples of the weights of and update the probabilistic model using the error of the expectation of the cost function (so I am basically sampling the cost distribution using Monte Carlo samples). That means that I have to forward pass the NN x times for different weight samples, calculate the expectation of the cost and finally backpropagate the error of the expectation (all in the same run). 
Here is a simplified example of what I would like to do:

```
w = tf.Variable(1.0) # the weights of the NN
u = tf.random_uniform([1]) # Random generator
cost = tf.mul(w,u)

# here I wish to take 10 MC samples
for i in range(9): 
    # this is the part which I dont know how to implement
    cost = tf.add(cost,new_cost_sample)

cost_mean = cost/10.0

train = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(lrate).minimize(cost_mean)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
    sess.run(train)
```

The `new_cost_sample` should be the result of multiplying the weight variable `w` with another random sampled number `u` from the uniform distribution.

Since Tensorflow stores the values of the operators during the same forward pass, I cannot just call the `cost` op multiple times. I could use `sess.run(cost)` 10 times and calculate its expectation, but then I dont know how to feed this error to the training op.

There would also be the possibility of using placeholders for the random generators and then feed them to the network, but this would take a big amount of space for big NN and I dont think this would be the most elegant/effective way to implement this.

Is there a method to tell an op to recalculate its values during the same run? Can you think of an effective way to implement this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a for loop to compute `cost_mean`; it's not efficient. Instead, I would rather use a vectorized implementation computing the mean with [`tf.reduce_mean()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#reduce_mean):

```
w = tf.Variable(1.0)  # the weights of the NN
u = tf.random_uniform([10])  # Random generator
cost = tf.mul(w, u)
cost_mean = tf.reduce_mean(cost)
```

Comment: The problem I see by doing so is that this implementation could easily take a huge amount of space. You will have for each of the weights of the NN a vector of lenght 10, which is equivalent to having 10 NN with different weights.
It would be nicer if I could keep the size of the NN the same by generating another random number for each forward pass and cummulate the sum of the cost (or in any other way).

Comment: I believe this is as space-efficient as your initial idea. You're just using tf.random_uniform() to generate values, you aren't storing them as variables. I hope this helps, I can't imagine any better way to do that :)